# alternative for raster::extract to extract values from a shapefile

Tags: r, extract, osx-mavericks, raster

I have map of ecoregions in shapefile format and a set of data points coordinates. What I would like to do is for each point extract the ecoregion where it falls.

This is what `raster::extract()` does. However, it seems that for this to work the package [rgeos](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/index.html) is necessary, and this is not available for >= OS X Mavericks, which is my case.

Any idea of how could I extract this info w/o using `extract()`? Or could you please tell me if I'm missing something on how to get `raster` to properly work on my system (OS X Yosemite, R 3.1.2)?

Comment: Does `sp::over` perform the required task?

Comment: The last request makes me wonder whether you know that many of the functions in `raster` and `sp` require that NCDF, NCDF4, GDAL and GEOS (external to R) packages be installed.

Comment: are the ecoregions in shapefile format or raster format?

Comment: `sp::over` is the function `over` in the package `sp`

Comment: Cheers @mnel that works. Just had to convert the coords to SpatialPoints.